# How default neovim filetype=sshconfig for files in .ssh/config.d/?

Tags: vim, neovim

I like to separate my ssh config files and include config files in a subdirectory `.ssh/config.d/*` as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1142813). When opening `.ssh/config` in neovim I get syntax highlighting with filetype `filetype=sshconfig` automatically but not for included config files in `.ssh/config.d/`.

What can I do to achieve automatic file type recognition (`filetype=sshconfig`) within that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-detection of filetype for Neovim is in `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/filetype.lua` : `sshconfig` filetype is not detected for file in `~/.ssh/config.d/` directory.

You can create an [auto-command with Neovim API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_create_autocmd()) to set your filetype :

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'BufRead', 'BufNewFile'}, {
  desc = 'Set filetype for SSH config directory',
  pattern = '*/.ssh/config.d/*',
  command = 'set filetype=sshconfig'
})
```

Comment: OK it does not work when I put this code into `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/filetype.lua` but it does work when I place it into `.config/nvim/init.nvim` in a `lua << ` heredoc. So it works in the per user setting exactly as I want it. Thank you.

Comment: @phinz I haven't used Neovim, but I still remind you that do not try to modify the system files. In addition, if you use `.config/nvim/init.vim` to configure, you can just use `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead */.ssh/config.d/* setfiletype sshconfig`, there is no need to call the Nvim lua API again in the *vim* file. Otherwise, you can directly use `init.lua` to configure.